# IOS/Safari dropdowns are pre-selected

Tags: javascript, angular, dropdown

I am using angular 5 to create this web app. When i launch it on Iphone using safari, the drop-downs's first option is pre-selected. How do i make it a blank option?

here is some of the code. I have tried adding an empty option but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<select class="form-control" id="group" formControlName="groupId">
    <option selected disabled hidden></option>
    <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value] = "group.groupId">
        {{group.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: remove the` selected` attribute

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka tried that. Still the same

Comment: I'm not surprised since the first option is disabled and hidden (not a valid attribute). Try making the first option `<option vale=""></option>`. When you open the select I guess there will be a blank option though, why not just have something meaningful there like "Please select a group"?